Pass a template class as a template argument
First, I didn't know how to describe the problem shortly in the title, sorry about that.
I am doing a mesh code. I want to make the code the most abstract possible.
A mesh is a cloud of points organized in a certain topology resulting in a set of polyhedron.
I want, at the very bottom, to define simplices and quadrangles (not really sure of the name). These are not related yet to the mesh. It describes only the topology of these forms.
Hence I have a class simplex:
template<int D> //D is the dimension of the simplex (0 is a point, 1 an edge, 2 a triangle,...)
class simplex
{
   static constexpr int nb_included_simplices[4]; 
}

similarly
template<int D> //D is the dimension of the simplex (0 is a point, 1 an edge, 2 a triangle,...)
class quadrangle
{
   static constexpr int nb_included_quadrangle[4]; 
}

The nb_included_whatever are define at the compile time. Some other attributes may pop in the future.
The difficulty for comes now.
I now want to have a class entity which discribes an entity of the mesh. That is it can be a simplex or a quadrangle (I suppose the mesh contains either only simplices, either only quadrangles) and contains all the incidence entities (the entities of the mesh that "touch" this entity).
It should look like this (although I know it is wrong)
template<typename T, int D> //T is the type of the entity (simplex or quadrangle)
class entity
{
   std::vector<T<0>> incident0;
   std::vector<T<1>> incident1;
   std::vector<T<2>> incident2;
   std::vector<T<3>> incident3;
}

The idea is to precise in the declaration of the entity its type. For example for a triangle of the mesh entity<simplex,2> T.
I don't know how I can do this.
The final idea will be to precise at the mesh declaration, the type of the entities, for example mesh<simplex,3> for a mesh in 3D composed of tetrahedron.
Making the difference will be important in the future of the project.

It's called template template parameter.

Thanks, I did not know the existence of this. So this would be something like template< template<class> T, int D> ?

template<template<int> typename T, int D> I believe.

I does work, thanks

No problem. You can post an answer to your own question. (It's prefered to editing a solution into the question, plus you can get some bonus rep that way).

How do I pass a template as a template parameter to a template?

Thanks to @super, I now have the solution:
template<template<int> typename T, int D> //T is the type of the entity (simplex or quadrangle)
class entity
{
   std::vector<T<0>> incident0;
   std::vector<T<1>> incident1;
   std::vector<T<2>> incident2;
   std::vector<T<3>> incident3;
}

